# gcc cannot find function in lib

Tags: c, linux, gcc, lib

I am trying to make a C program using libmbus, which I have installed on my raspberry pi. In my /usr/lib directory I have the file libmbus.so and in my /usr/include directory I have the the file ./mbus/mbus.h.

The program looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mbus/mbus.h>

int main(void)
{
    mbus_handle* MbusHandle;

    MbusHandle = mbus_connect_serial("/dev/ttyS1");

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run "gcc main.cpp -lmbus" I get:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `mbus_connect_serial(char const*)'
```

I tried to run

```
nm -D /usr/lib/libmbus.so
```

which among others gives

```
00009930 T mbus_connect_serial
```

So it appears that the function mbus_connect_serial is part of libmbus.so.

In the header file the function mbus_connect_serial is defined like this:

```
mbus_handle * mbus_connect_serial(const char * device);
```

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Your error message indicates that your question should be about `c++`. Also, the compiler is not the one complaining.

Comment: you could try `extern "C" { #include <mbus/mbus.h> };`. Can you check if `mbus.h` contains some `extern "C"` directives? if it doesn't it means that the C++ compiler generates a C++ prototype (with arguments) instead of a C prototype (without arguments)

Comment: oh, that could be a problem of calling `gcc` on a C++ file also: try: `g++ main.cpp -lmbus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really trying to create a `c` program, rename `main.cpp` to `main.c`

Comment: This solved my issue. Thanks. I didn't know that gcc was looking at the extensions of the files. However, I did not have this problem with other C programs I made with the extension .cpp. Could this be because of the structure of the lib I am trying to use here?

Comment: `g++` and `.cpp` files mean `c++`.  Name mangling in `c++` will prevent the linker from finding functions in the library.  I don't know this specific library so I can't help you there.  BTW, if this solved your problem, please accept it as the solution.